# How Do you split a string like this? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I am currently trying to create a random image generator in PHP, and I'm having a hard time setting the file path, I can get all the file paths, but they are in one long string, like this.

`" ../images/box1/IMG_3158.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3161.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3163.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3158.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3161.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3163.JPG"`

with the `" .."` marking the beginning of a new file.

How would i explode ( or something of the kind ) each file_path to return them separately?

Comment: I assume this is PHP?

Comment: Yes, I added PHP into the title and tags for clarity. Thankyou.

Comment: why are the file paths in one long string like that in the first place?  how are you getting them and why are they not in an array?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you can do this.

```
$data  = '../images/box1/IMG_3158.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3161.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3163.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3158.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3161.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3163.JPG';
$files = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?=\.{2})/', $data);
print_r($files);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => ../images/box1/IMG_3158.JPG
    [1] => ../images/box1/IMG_3161.JPG
    [2] => ../images/box1/IMG_3163.JPG
    [3] => ../images/box1/IMG_3158.JPG
    [4] => ../images/box1/IMG_3161.JPG
    [5] => ../images/box1/IMG_3163.JPG
)
```

Regular Expression:

```
(?<!            look behind to see if there is not:
  ^               the beginning of the string
)               end of look-behind
(?=             look ahead to see if there is:
  \.{2}           '.' (2 times)
)               end of look-ahead
```

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please explain the regex, it looks impressive for men and please dont post the results of [http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?) lol. Little more breakdown needed

Comment: @shatheesh It first looks behind to make sure there is not the beginning of the string so we don't capture an empty result while splitting, while it looks ahead marking the position before `..`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
//Since new file path is starting from ".." we explode it using ".." and added to each file path.


      $string ="../images/box1/IMG_3158.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3161.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3163.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3158.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3161.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3163.JPG";
      $file_path=explode('..',$string);
      $i=0;
      while(isset($file_path[++$i])){
        $file_path[$i]="..".$file_path[$i];
        echo $file_path[$i]."<br />";

      }

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

### http://ideone.com/MTRr9Q

Just use `explode()`

```
$file_paths = explode('..', $input);
```

**Example**

```
$string = "../images/box1/IMG_3158.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3161.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3163.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3158.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3161.JPG../images/box1/IMG_3163.JPG";
$file_paths = explode('..', $string);
var_dump($file_paths);
```

This strips of the `".."` at the beginning, so try to append it yourself.  For more complicated situations, a `preg_split()` would be an appropriate task. Given that your string doesn't change, then an explode could do.

Comment: yeah It kind of hit me when I was asking the question, I just couldn't see where to find a reference to create the delimiter.
----- 
What would you do if those dots wern't there?

Comment: Well, the first parameter is the delimiter, put in place of the ".." whatever the delimiter is, it can be a "." or a "-" or whatever

Comment: ah, okay. Thanks i'll play around with this!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to introduce an otherwise unused character between each path as you import(?) the list of path names, you could then use that character as your delimiter instead of ".." (refer to Ali's answer).